# linux to windows migration tips and tools

Tags: windows, linux, migration

I'm looking for any tips and tools that would help me migrate from a Linux (Ubuntu) installation to Windows. The computer (laptop) is already installed with both (dual boot).

Specific issues:

- Is how to access my ext3 partition from Windows. Since it is larger than my Windows partition, I'm hoping for some way of booting to Windows, being able to continue to work with data and then start to shrink the ext3 partition and increase the Windows(NTFS) one, moving the data

  Any pointers on making cygnus work with my existing home folder (which also means being able to mount the ext3 partition) will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my great surprise there is a Windows driver for ext3: http://fs-driver.org/

If that doesn't work for whatever reason you could also try converting your ext3 partition to NTFS, which you can then access in both Linux and Windows. In fact, if you want to be really safe, make it FAT instead. You would need to do this manually - backup, format and restore. Obviously you'd be giving up Linux file permissions and other file system features by doing this, but if it's a single-user home computer that might be OK.

Comment: +1 I've used this specific EXT driver and it works well. Just note that it mounts EXT3 partitions as EXT2, which means there is no journaling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try install vmWare. You can get vmWare server version for free with registration.

Run the Linux inside vmware under Windows.
Setup Samba to share Linux file with windows.

I do this all the time in my laptop.  It works very well for me.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: @MarkM That is a legitimate, if roundabout, way to get access to the files while booted into Windows.