# Is there any tool to read ext3 partition directly in XP

Tags: drivers, windows-xp, ext3

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [linux to windows migration tips and tools](https://superuser.com/questions/82896/linux-to-windows-migration-tips-and-tools)
>   [Mount ext3fs in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows)

I am using WinXP and I have a partition in ext3 format.
How can I read the content in this partition just as access a ordinary partition?

Is there any tools or drivers?

Many thanks!

Comment: This question would be answered better at superuser.com. It will move there soon.

Comment: Doen't belong to SO. Look at the superuser.com, for example http://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux to windows migration tips and tools](http://superuser.com/questions/82896/linux-to-windows-migration-tips-and-tools) and http://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

There is a [driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/) and an [explorer tool](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs). Generally installing the driver, then restarting will make it appear as a standard drive letter. Be careful with subtle differences such as permissions, case sensitivity and character support.

Comment: I have used FS Driver in the past and found that it lead to data corruption issues on the ext3 partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these tools to help you

- [FS-Driver](http://www.fs-driver.org/)
- [LinuxReader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/)